# Is there a way using keypress to change the focus writting( '| ' )from an input to another?

Tags: javascript, events, input

I have to inputs, and I want to press enter and change the attention from first input to second input without using only the mouse.

So far I created an Event Listener in the first input (jogador1) with keypress event. Inside I made a conditional if the first Input(jogador1) has already a value which is a number and the keypress is 13 then should do something that is changing to the second input. Is That part I don't know.

here is my code :

```
let jogador1 = document.querySelector('#jogador1');
let jogador2 =document.querySelector('#jogador2');
let output = document.querySelector('#output');

let button = document.querySelector('#button');

let letsCompareValues = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let value1 = jogador1.value;
    let value2 = jogador2.value;
    if (value1 === value2 && !isNaN(value1) && !isNaN(value2)) {

        output.innerHTML = 'there is a match';
        return
    } else {

        output.innerHTML ='there is no match';
    }

}

button.addEventListener('click', letsCompareValues);

jogador1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    jogador1.value = '';
    jogador2.value = '';
    output.innerHTML = '';
});

//HERE
jogador1.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if(jogador1.value !== isNaN && code === 13){
        jogador2.focus;

    }
})
```

```
   <div>
       <label for="jogador1">Player 1</label>
       <input type="text" id="jogador1">
   </div>
   <div>
       <label for="jogador2">Player 2</label>
       <input type="text" id="jogador2">
   </div>



   <button id="button">JOGAR</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. `element.focus()` is a function, so you need the parenthesis to invoke it.

Other issues:

- You're referring to an element with id 'output', but don't have such an element.
- You're using `!== isNaN` to check if a string is not empty. You should instead use `str !== ''`, or better yet just `str`.
- Use `keyEvent.key` instead of `keyEvent.code`.
- Tidy up your code before asking people to spend their time reading it. It's a reflection on you.
- Use minimal examples, not code dumps, when posting on stack overflow.

```js
let jogador1 = document.querySelector('#jogador1');
let jogador2 = document.querySelector('#jogador2');
let output = document.querySelector('#output');

let button = document.querySelector('#button');

let letsCompareValues = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let value1 = jogador1.value;
  let value2 = jogador2.value;
  if (value1 === value2 && !isNaN(value1) && !isNaN(value2)) {

    output.innerHTML = 'there is a match';
    return
  } else {

    output.innerHTML = 'there is no match';
  }

}

button.addEventListener('click', letsCompareValues);

jogador1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  jogador1.value = '';
  jogador2.value = '';
  output.innerHTML = '';
});

jogador1.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (jogador1.value && e.key === 'Enter') {
    jogador2.focus();

  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="jogador1">Player 1</label>
  <input type="text" id="jogador1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="jogador2">Player 2</label>
  <input type="text" id="jogador2">
</div>

<div id="output"></diV>

<button id="button">JOGAR</button>
```